# Project management software with source control, task lists, notifications, wiki

Tags: project-management, knowledge-organization, knowledge-base, issue-tracker

I am starting a software development project of 6 people, and I am looking for a configuration that will allow the following features:

- Create and assign tasks.
- Front end for source control
- Content managemen, e.g Wiki
- Notify user X when someone adds/updates/comments on a task that is assigned to X.
- Notify user X when someone updates a wiki page X is subscribed to (so there is an option to subscribe to Wiki pages)
- Can view a user list and see for each user what their tasks, commits, wiki entries.

It seems like Trac would come quite close, I am not sure if it allows viewing a user as mentioned and about notifications. I am also not sure if it is the best software available for these purposes.

Could you specify a software that would match these features as closely as possible?

Cheers!

Comment: "I am not sure if it allows..." Well, then dig into it and find it. This is not a 'can you do my work for me' site.

Comment: Search this site for Trac, it has at least 5 answers recommending it in similar content. And yes, Trac can notify a user if he's owner of a ticket (or added himself to CC), which is done by mail. Never tried that with Wiki pages, but AFAIK there's at least a plugin for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is [GForge Advanced Server](https://gforge.com/gf/#feature) it has all of the features you mention and is basically a commercial, self hosted, version of [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at http://www.Project.net . Its Open Source so you can install it yourself or you can sign up for a free trial for the latest Commercially hosted version.